# How to setup an automatic redirect from a route to a specific HTML file in that folder?

Tags: html, wordpress, hosting, redirect

**Situation:** I've given out a link to some people (say: `mydomain.me/projects/project1/`). When they navigate to that link, I need the page `mydomain.me/projects/project1/project1.html` to be displayed.

**Question:** Is there a way to redirect all queries to the first link so that the second link is actually opened? (Possibly similar to how requests to the root of your server automatically navigate to index.html/php?)

**More detailed explanation:** I've recently applied to a couple of jobs with my (pdf) resume containing the first link. Thus, when the employer clicks on the link, it'll take them to my current web page where certain projects are displayed in more detail. This web page was made using WordPress and there is some sort of backend script allowing navigation into that folder to display the project. Currently, I'm remaking my website from scratch and I want to display the same project (no longer being hosted on the WordPress site) as an HTML file. Soon, I'll be migrating my personal domain to point to my new site as opposed to the old WordPress one. When this happens, I want the employers to be able to still use the same link to navigate to my newly made project.html pages.

Comment: what hosting are you using ?

Comment: @FadySadek I'm not certain what you mean by *host*. My current site is hosted on **Host Gator** using WordPress to run it. My new site is currently being developed locally, then I'll be hosting it on a **DigitalOcean** droplet.